# Social Authentication with Djoser in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am new to Django and it's features.

I started new project with Djoser as authentication library and now I would like to implement social authentication via Google, Facebook etc.

I found so much libraries but some suggestions were about using custom user model or not for rest library.

Is there any library that can work with Djoser?